# For Loop for a Fourier Series Equation

Tags: python, numpy

How can I plot the Fourier Series equation below, using a for loop where I can change n, instead of writing out the `cos(x) + cos(2x) + cos(3x)`, etc.?

My script is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
pi  = np.pi
x = np.linspace(-pi,pi,100)
ao = (1/(2*pi))
y = ao + (1/pi)*(np.cos(x)+np.cos(2*x)+np.cos(3*x) + np.cos(4*x)+np.cos(5*x)+np.cos(6*x) + np.cos(7*x) + np.cos(8*x) + np.cos(9*x)+np.cos(10*x))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
pi  = np.pi
n = 10
x = np.linspace(-pi,pi,100)
y = (1/(2*pi)) + (1/pi)*(sum(np.cos(i * x) for i in xrange(1, n)))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Basically you just have a list comprehension which does the sum for you:

`sum(np.cos(i * x) for i in xrange(1, n))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
n = 10
y = ao + (1/pi) * sum([np.cos((i+1)*x) for i in range(n)])
```